# Multiple table sorting using Tablesorter JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery Tablesorter in different tables and it is working fine. Now I am trying to sort different way where one table contain `table thead` and another table contain `table tbody`. My table looks like -

```
<table id="tbl" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Age</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>  
</table>
<table id="tbl1"> 
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>21</td>
           <td>abc</td>
           <td>82</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>12</td>
           <td>ttt</td>
           <td>90</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this or this is not possible in Tablesorter.

Thanks

Comment: you can add both thead and tbody into one table

Comment: @PrashantPatil, for some other functionalities, I cannot use thead in 1 table

Comment: yes i saw it. but if you applying table sorter on one table so it cant apply on another table automatically

Comment: @PrashantPatil, when I am using thead and tbody in same table, my other functions stopped working, so I need to separate that

Comment: oh its not possible.. you need to change into core js file of table sorter for your purpose